# Update iplookUp cache periodically with original database file

Tags: scala, maxmind

I want to create a cache for iplookups from maxmind database file GeoIP-City.mmdb.
Problem is if my application is running and the original database gets updated from maxmind, how my code will get the updated file contents without being restarted?

The code which read the data from maxmind file is

```
val ipLooksUps: IO[IpLookups[IO]] = IpLookups.createFromFilenames(
    Some(geoFilePath),
    None,
    None,
    None,
    false,
    20000
  )
```

now ipLookups has the data for ip address and city mapping. How to update it automatically while my application is running

Comment: Are you deploying your app manually?

Answer (score 1):

You could use fs2-cron library https://github.com/fthomas/fs2-cron

```
case class Look() {
    val ipLooksUps: IO[IpLookups[IO]] = IpLookups.createFromFilenames(
    Some(geoFilePath),
    None,
    None,
    None,
    false,
    20000)
}

import cats.effect.{IO, Timer}
import cron4s.Cron
import eu.timepit.fs2cron.awakeEveryCron
import fs2.Stream
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

implicit val timer: Timer[IO] = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.global)


val cron      = Cron.unsafeParse("*/2 * * ? * *")
val scheduled = awakeEveryCron[IO](cron) >> Stream.eval(IO(Look()))
scheduled.compile.drain.unsafeRunAsyncAndForget()
```